# $\sum_{k=1}^{k=\infty} \frac{z^{k+x}}{k+x}$ = what?

Tags: taylor-expansion, geometric-series

When |z| < 1, from geometric series,

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} z^k = \frac{1}{1-z}$$

By integration,

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{z^k}{k} = -\log{(1-z)}$$

This formula also can be verified by Taylor series of $-\log{(1-z)}$.

Then, what about 
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{z^{k+x}}{k+x}$$

for $0 \le x < 1$ ?

In the same way,

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} z^{k+x} = \frac{z^x}{1-z}$$

By integration,

$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{z^{k+x}}{k+x} =& \int_0^z \frac{w^x}{1-w} dw \\
                                  =& \left[ \frac{w^x}{(1-w)\log(w)} \right]_0^z dw \\
                                  =& \frac{z^x}{(1-z)\log(z)} 
\end{align}
$$

This formula should be same with $-\log(1-z)$ when $x=0$.

Howevery, it is not.

What mistake I did?

What is the correct formula?

I stuck here.

Comment: The problem is when you do the integration.

Comment: Are the indices in your sums meant to be in $k$ instead of $j$?

Comment: Eevee Trainer > Yes. I fix it. I'm sorry.

Comment: Lord Shark the Unknown > Integration is not correct?

Comment: You can **check** your integration; differentiate your final expression with respect to $z$, and see whether you get $z^x/(1-z)$.

Comment: I finally see what you did. You integrated with respect to $x$, not with respect to $w$.

Comment: I use mathematica wrongly. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are in the domain of special functions
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{z^{k+x}}{k+x}=z^{x+1} \Phi (z,1,x+1)$$ where appears the [Hurwitz-Lerch transcendent function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LerchTranscendent.html).

If you want to compute the antiderivative
$$I=\int \frac{w^x}{1-w}\, dw =\frac{w^{x+1} }{x+1} \, _2F_1(1,x+1;x+2;w)$$ where appears the [gaussian hypergeometric function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function).

Now, for 
$$J=\int_0^z \frac{w^x}{1-w}\, dw =B_z(x+1,0) \qquad \text{if} \qquad (\Re(z)<1\lor z\notin \mathbb{R})\land \Re(x)>-1$$ where appears the [incomplete beta function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IncompleteBetaFunction.html).